# How to make sure to limit the scope of a task?

Tags: colleagues, task-management

I am working on 10 projects currently at my job, I literally do everything and I was asked by IT to write an enormous documentation on what every button does and document every logic. I only worked in the company for 1.6 years, so I am not sure if it makes sense and I only worked on the applications to solve issues and they were the same (40 roughly and 4 different types of bugs). Now, the IT is asking me to do something that's completely useless in my eyes, so how do I force them to stop asking me to do unreasonable things and limit the scope of the work they've requested of me (writing a documentation for every little feature in the application). The product manager heard IT request and made a task for me.

Comment: You can't stop them from *asking* you. Let them *ask* all they want.

Comment: Whom do you work for? Do you have an immediate boss or supervisor? Only one person should be giving you tasks. Anyone else who needs you to do something should be asking your boss to tell you to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's very common for companies to literally forget how to use their own software. You added a report for Accounting, but it wasn't really for Accounting, it was for Steve in Accounting, and after he left, nobody ran that report, but now they're kinda wondering what it does and if it might be useful. You added a button that says Confirm and sometimes it's enabled and sometimes it's not and it was Elaine in Customer Service who asked you to add it but Elaine got transferred to Japan and the current Customer Service people are super frustrated because they don't know how to enable that Confirm button and what they need to do to get it to work. You add an export feature for your biggest customer, and someone isn't really sure just what it exports and nobody remembers and someone looked at the .csv file but it was just numbers and dates and they don't have any documentation on what the data really is. This is even worse if you didn't add those things; they were added by the developer before you, the one who is gone now, and you don't know either so when people ask you, all they get is "I have no idea, I didn't write that and nothing is written down about it."

After a while, enough of this piles up, the software gets less and less useful. You know that if you add another report for Joanna in Accounting, another button for Phil in Customer Service, that you're making the application more useful. You have a giant list of those requests and bug fixes on top of that, and you're busy. So you don't really want to help anyone figure out what that Confirm button does, or what's in the export, or what that accounting report was for. But that won't stop them needing to know those things to do their jobs well.

You need to stop thinking of this as completely useless and unreasonable. At this point, the only way anyone is going to understand what enables the Confirm button (well, you know, the equivalent thing in your software) is if someone who can read code (and it seems like the only candidate for that is you) goes and finds the code that enables it, and reads it, and translates that into English like "it has to be paid for and it can't be more than 30 days in the future."  This is the sort of work that makes the application still useful even as the people who asked for features come and go.

What's more, it can make your job easier too. In my experience, when there's a lot of churn, people report "bugs" that are actually "the software is doing exactly what we asked, but we don't remember what we asked, and we would like something different today, so we are just going to say your software has a bug." They also ask for things they already have, because those things are on a page they never look at or behind a button none of them understand. If there is good user documentation, they may pester you a lot less to do things that don't need to be done, or they may make you (and your boss) happier by not saying "your software is broken, this should be in alphabetical order" and instead saying "I know this was written to be in date order, but now we'd prefer alphabetical order."

This kind of task is perfect for filling the gaps between bugs, or those days when you're tired from bug chasing and want to do something simple. **Here's how to limit, if not the scope, at least the amount of your time that it takes away from fixing bugs and adding features.** Create a manual, outline it somehow (page by page maybe, or according to the jobs of the different people who use it, some sensible structure), put in some screen shots, and then over time, fill it in. What does that report show? What enables that button? What do the 4 choices in that drop down box actually change about how things work? Keep the draft somewhere that people can see it as it grows. And of course, when you fix a bug or add a feature, and all that "how it works" part is fresh in your head, you can write that part of the manual as part of doing the bug or feature work.

Will you end up documenting every single feature in the app? Eventually. But you do the stuff in a sensible order. Start with the things people get confused about, ask about, use up your time with. Put more energy into the parts that are getting lots of new features and bug fixes and less into the parts that are well understood or not used at all. Co-operate. Be cheerful! And give your boss what your boss has asked for. At any given moment it's probably lower priority than your top bug, but give it some time every week and it will get done.

Comment: This could be a good answer **if** it was trimmed to the essentials.

Answer (score 4):

In many companies, it is normal to be asked to do too much. The solution is to ask your boss to prioritize your tasks. Work on the most important tasks and let the others go. If the person who wants that task done complains, tell them to talk to your boss as your boss set your priorities.